# React Native with Expo, fontFamily not apply to stackNavigator header title by headerTitleStyle

Tags: react-native, expo

React Native with Expo, fontFamily not apply to stackNavigator header title by headerTitleStyle, the font is work fine on app screens, but not apply on stackNavigator header title. any help.

```js
    Home: {screen : Home,
    navigationOptions: {
      headerLeft: null,
      title: 'Home',
      headerTitleStyle: {fontFamily: 'myFont', fontSize: 20,},
      headerStyle: { marginTop: 24, },
    },
  },
```

Answer (score 4):

I found the problem, the font dose not apply on any text that takes

```
fontWeight: 'bold',
```

so you need to set fontWeight to value less than 500

```
fontWeight: '200',
```

```js
headerTitleStyle: {fontWeight: '200', fontFamily: 'myFont', fontSize: 16,},
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use
    "**fontWeight: undefined**" inside the headerTitleStyle.

For Example :

```
headerTitleStyle: {
    fontFamily: 'Roboto-Bold',
    fontWeight:undefined,
}
```

Comment: This fixed my issue. No one else has suggested this on all the forums.